# Template file not working in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an external JSON template file to load into ElasticSearch

This is what I do:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_template/mytemplate' -d @file.json
```

The command get correctly acknowledged

Unfortunately when the index is created the rules defined inside my JSON file are not applied

**EDIT**

This is the JSON file

```
{
    "template" : "log-*",
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "logEvent": {
            "properties": {
                "timeStamp": {
                    "type": "date",
                    "format": "dateOptionalTime"
                },
                "message": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "messageObject": {
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "exception": {
                    "type": "object"
                },
                "loggerName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "domain": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "identity": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "level": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "className": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "fileName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "lineNumber": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "fullInfo": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "methodName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "fix": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "userName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "threadName": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "hostName": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which should be applied to any index matching `log-*`. One of those index is `log-2016.07.28`

The template specifies the type of `lineNumber`. It should change the type of such `lineNumber` field from the default `string` to `long`. What I get is a document with `lineNumber` as a `string`.

This is the returned document:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "log-2016.07.28",
      "_type" : "logEvent",
      "_id" : "AVYwvw-k6GHUP7T-sYlL",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "timeStamp" : "2016-07-28T09:04:02.8994786Z",
        "message" : "Upload file operation took 600 ms",
        "messageObject" : { },
        "exception" : { },
        "loggerName" : "Reviewer.Web.WebApi.GroupsController",
        "domain" : "/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-131141667495593380",
        "identity" : "",
        "level" : "INFO",
        "className" : "Reviewer.Logger.MethodTimer",
        "fileName" : "MethodTimer.cs",
        "lineNumber" : "49",
        "fullInfo" : "MethodTimer.cs:49)",
        "methodName" : "Dispose",
        "fix" : "LocationInfo, UserName, Identity, Partial",
        "properties" : {
          "test" : "123",
          "log4net:HostName" : "GBWOTIOM68052D",
          "IP" : "::1",
          "log4net:Identity" : "",
          "log4net:UserName" : "CORP\\gianluca.ghettini",
          "log4net:ElapsedTime" : "600",
          "@timestamp" : "2016-07-28T09:04:02.8994786Z"
        },
        "userName" : "CORP\\gianluca.ghettini",
        "threadName" : "198",
        "hostName" : "GBWOTIOM68052D"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

as you can see the

```
"lineNumber" : "49",
```

is still a `string` instead of a `long`

Comment: So how you index and what is wrong?

Comment: Can you show how you index your log documents? Please show one sample document.

Comment: I just added a sample document, what I'd like to have and what I actually get instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you observe is the **source of the document** (as it was sent to ES) and ES will never change it. If your source contains a string value, you'll see a string value, if your source contains a numeric value, you'll see a number value in the source.

However, the way the data is indexed is what really matters. If your mapping declares a given field to be a string, the field value in the source (be it a number, a boolean, a string or whatever) will be indexed as a string.

If your mapping declares a given field to be a number and the field value in the source is a string, ES will try to coerce the string into a number and that number will be indexed, however, **the string in the source will not be changed to a number**.

So, in your case, you send `lineNumber` as the string `"49"`, so ES will coerce the string `"49"` to the number `49` and index that number, even though, the source will still contain the string `"49"`.

To sum it up, if you really want to see a number in your source, you need to send a number, i.e. `"lineNumber": 49` instead of `"lineNumber": "49"`

Comment: brilliant! Is there a way to know if I got the "right" type? Is it possible to query ES for such info?

Comment: I mean, I way to actually verify the field has got the right type internally

Comment: Trust your mapping and ES for doing its job ;)

Comment: of course. My only concern is that the field I'm trying to change is not actually  "lineNumber" but instead "log4net:ElapsedTime" which is inside the "properties" object, an unfortunate name for a field ("properties" is also the JSON keyword used by ES to define the field list)

Comment: You can definitely modify your mapping to include the `properties` object and the mappings of its inner fields.